# How to add rows and columns in GridView using a button event in Android?

Tags: android

I have created a `GridView` with three rows and three columns, each with text fields in them. Upon clicking a button, the user may require either rows or columns to be created so that they can create an extra tier to the "table". How is this implemented?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you attempted to solve this problem? If you have, include your code and research in your question to show what hasn't worked for you. If not, you should attempt to solve it yourself first and then post the code and research here. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One does not simply create table with rows and columns without data.

You can only use method `setNumColumns` to defines how many columns to show:

> ***public void setNumColumns (int numColumns)***
>
> Added in API level 1
>  *Set the number of columns in the grid*
>
> **Related XML Attributes** 
>  android:numColumns 
>  **Parameters**
>  *numColumns* -  The
>   desired number of columns.

link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#setNumColumns(int)

This means, that you can only set columns number but **not rows number**.
If you need `GridView` *3x3*, then you need *9 items* for your `GridView` and *set number of colums to 3*.
If you need `GridView` *7x2* you need *14 items* for your `GridView` and *set number of colums to 7*.

I have wrote some example, to help you implement what you need.

---

**`MainActivity.java`:**

```
package com.dinamicgridview.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[] data = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"};

    GridView mGridView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.gridview_item, R.id.tv_text, data);
        mGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mGridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        adjustGridView(4);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_adjust_1) {
            adjustGridView(1);
            return true;
        }else if(id == R.id.action_adjust_2){
            adjustGridView(2);
            return true;
        }else if(id == R.id.action_adjust_3){
            adjustGridView(3);
            return true;
        }else if(id == R.id.action_adjust_4){
            adjustGridView(4);
            return true;
        }else if(id == R.id.action_adjust_5){
            adjustGridView(5);
            return true;
        }else if(id == R.id.action_adjust_6){
            adjustGridView(6);
            return true;
        }else if(id == R.id.action_adjust_7){
            adjustGridView(7);
            return true;
        }else if(id == R.id.action_adjust_8){
            adjustGridView(8);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void adjustGridView(int numColumns) {
        mGridView.setNumColumns(numColumns);
    }
}
```

**`menu_main.xml`**:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_adjust_1"
          android:title="Adjust 1"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_adjust_2"
          android:title="Adjust 2"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_adjust_3"
          android:title="Adjust 3"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_adjust_4"
          android:title="Adjust 4"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_adjust_5"
          android:title="Adjust 5"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_adjust_6"
          android:title="Adjust 6"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_adjust_7"
          android:title="Adjust 7"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_adjust_8"
          android:title="Adjust 8"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

**`activity_main.xml`**:

```
<GridView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnWidth="70dp"
    android:minHeight="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

**`gridview_item.xml`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:id="@+id/tv_text"
            android:text=""/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Demo**:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot... this makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @CanaanNyoni, I see that you novice on `stackoverflow.com`. So, if my answer was helpful, you can accept it, to help other people find answer on same question. You should press on green check to left of my answer